# Windows Command Prompt Deleting files in folders

Tags: windows, cmd, delete-file

After a backup every file on a disk looks like `filename_1.jpg`

I am using `del *_1.*` to delete the file.s But can I use the command in D:\ to work down each folder either?

At present I use `del *_1.*` then `cd ..` the cd into the next dir, and so on.

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be very, very careful with this command. One false move and you can do a lot of damage...

First try

```
dir /b /s "d:\*_1.*"
```

which should show you a list of target files to check. If you like, you can use `"d:\somedirectory\*_1.*"` to start at some subdirectory.

Once you're satisfied with your list, the command you want is

```
del /s "d:\*_1.*"
```

Which I usually invoke by up-arrowing to return the previous command and editing the `DIR /B` to `DEL` to make sure that I don't change the filemask.

But as I say - use with extreme caution! The `/s` is the magic - it means 'and in subdirectories'